# iOS 11. Calendar is counting range of dates too long

Tags: ios, calendar, foundation, ios11

One of apps was worked perfectly under iOS 10, but after update to iOS 11, getting strange results, while counting date range over 10 seconds and more: `enumerateDates(startingAfter:matching:matchingPolicy:repeatedTimePolicy: direction:using)`

Does anyone faced with that?

Comment: What's the output? Show us the code, the expected result and the wrong result in iOS11.

Comment: @Shebuka I need enumerate all dates between two of them. This function simply used to store them in array for next processing. But under iOS 11 counting takes to long time.

Comment: @IgorKislyuk How do you expect anyone to tell you *why* it doesn't work as it supposed, when you refuse to provide any details when asked?

Comment: @mag_zbc the problem was in policy. Suppose they changed logic. I fixed my problem, but there is no time to figure it out. Let's close this

Comment: Then, for future reference, please post an answer with details on how did you fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error was in `matching policy` in Foundation call for iterating from start date to fill up the range. We are using `.previousTimePreservingSmallerComponents` and it is work perfectly on iOS 10. Otherwise, for preventing the bug in iOS 11 please fallback to `.strict` policy. Hope this can help someone.